# how do validate the data

Tags: c#

I have a class called `UserInfo` in which there are two properties Name and ID.

```
class UserInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and also i have one custom exception class called `UserAlreadyLoggedInException` which called in my main method when someone try to use the Name which is already taken by someone.

```
class UserAlreadyLoggedInException : Exception // 
{
    public UserAlreadyLoggedInException() : base()
    {

    }
    public UserAlreadyLoggedInException(string message) : base(message)
    {

    }
    public UserAlreadyLoggedInException(string message,Exception innerException) : base(message,innerException) 
    {

    }
```

Here It Is my `main` method.

```
try
        {
            UserInfo[] Ui = new UserInfo[3];
            Ui[0] = new UserInfo();
            Ui[1] = new UserInfo();
            Ui[2] = new UserInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Ui[i].Id = i;
                Console.WriteLine("Please inter the name of " + (i+1) + " user");
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Ui[i].Name = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Ui[i].Name = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (Ui[i].Name.Equals(Ui[i - 1].Name))
                    {
                        throw new UserAlreadyLoggedInException("UserName Has already taken");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().Name + ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

There are 3 objects of `UserInfo` Class when [0] index object called it directly take input without any logic because it is the first object.
when [1] index called it will go in to else statement because i here is = 1 , so it will take input and compare it with (i-1) which is zero index , if the name is present it will throw an exception.if the name does not match the loop will continue and the i will become 2 this time , and now again it will go towards else statement and take input , but the prob is here .... now it will compare it with (i - 1 ) which is now become [1] index .. so it will compare the name of 2nd index with 1st index , but not with 0 index .... 
how can i compare it with all of the indexes ???

Comment: Using dictionary might help
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your

```
if (Ui[i].Name.Equals(Ui[i - 1].Name)){
    throw ...
}
```

code into a loop that goes from 0 -> (i - 1).

So you'd have

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    // (if logic from above, but j instead of (i - 1))
}
```

Comment: let me check it ..

Comment: I've changed it quite a bit. I realized I made a few mistakes. Try with most recent changes

Comment: Thankyou genius .. it is working so nice

Comment: ben , can i ask , whats the prob in my question ? did i break any law of is it not clear what i was asking ? why someone has voted this as "down" ?

Comment: I think someone just didn't like your slightly broken English. People are just weird about that sometimes, and don't like questions that they have to work hard at to understand. In my opinion, you did nothing wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the entire array for the name before you assign it to any item. If you add `using System.Linq;` to your file, you can use the `Any()` extension method, which returns `true` if any item in the array matches the condition:

```
else
{
    string name = Console.ReadLine();

    // Before assigning the name to any item, see if it already exists
    if (Ui.Any(user => user.Name == name))
    {
        throw new UserAlreadyLoggedInException("UserName Has already taken");
    }

    // NOW assign the name
    Ui[i].Name = name;
}
```